# Can I copy and paste?

Tags: feature-request

I have a $6\times 6$ matrix in a comment that I wrote.  I wanted to copy it and paste it into a new question.

But apparently that can't be done.  After I post a comment, I can't click on "edit" unless, apparently, I do it within a few seconds, so I can't copy the TeX code.  And copying the rendered version doesn't give me the TeX code.

But in Wikipedia articles, I can copy the rendered version and then paste, and what gets pasted is the TeX code.

Is there some way to overcome this and copy-and-paste?

Comment: If you're at the point where you're writing $6 \times 6$ matrices, you should be taking the conversation out of the comments already...

Comment: "I can't click on edit unless, apparently, I do it within a few seconds" The number of seconds is 5*60 = 300.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. Rightclick the TeX code, such as $\int _{\alpha} ^\beta f(x) \mathrm{d} x$. There is the option to "show the source" - at least in Firefox. Open this, and it will show the TeX code. Copy this, put it in its own special set of \$ \$ marks, and you have duplicated the TeX.

Comment: +1, Excellent! I never knew this.

Comment: Anyone know the Mac-equivalent of Rightclick?

Comment: @Gerry Ctrl+click, which is easily found by Googling, e.g. "mac right click".

Comment: @Bill, thanks. I'll learn how to use this machine one of these days....